# disable command-delete osx shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't seem to find a way to disable command-delete shortcut in OSX.

This shortcut deletes files without warning also from save-as and load finder pages (e.g. when you save a page on disk from chrome, you can still accidentally remove a folder!)

Any suggestion is appreciated

alfonso

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, although not recommended. 
Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts. Then click the + button. Choose 'Finder' as your application, Menu title has to be exactly "Move to Trash" and enter a new shortcut. Click add, and you're all set. 

If you have any more questions, please shoot :)

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgPNw.png